# Where is the logging in my Django application started by uwsgi?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, logging, uwsgi

I use `supervisor` and `uwsgi` to start my Django. Here is the `conf` in supervisor.

```
[program:myapp]
directory=/home/users
command=uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=50MB
stdout_logfile_backups=30
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisor.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisor.log
```

And this is the `ini` file of `uwsgi`

```
[uwsgi]
http-socket=0.0.0.0:8080
wsgi-file=myapp/wsgi.py
logformat=%(ltime) "%(method) %(uri) %(proto)" status=%(status) res-time=%(msecs)ms
logto=/var/log/supervisor/uwsgi.log
```

In this way, only method, status and time to reponse etc is listed as follow

```
14/Jan/2022:13:19:46 +0800 "GET /model/task/?taskid=e69a757974f811ec93e1f58ac6e34980&current=1&pageSize=10000&total=0&model_id=1 HTTP/1.1" status=200 res-time=107ms
14/Jan/2022:13:19:45 +0800 "POST /model/runmodel/ HTTP/1.1" status=200 res-time=3508ms
```

What I want is if I add a `logging.info` or `logging.debug` in my application, it can also writes to the log file. From the [doc of uwsgi](https://uwsgi-docs-zh.readthedocs.io/zh_CN/latest/LogFormat.html), it seems I cannot accomplish that by the `logformat` parameter. Anyone knows if it's possible to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good day!

You are right, `logformat` handles only logging of the `uwsgi`.

If you want your Django app to log events you will need to add 2 things:

1. Update `settings.py`:

```py
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    "formatters": {
        "verbose": {
            "format": "[{asctime}] {levelname}: {name}.{message}",
            "style": "{",
        },
    },

    'handlers': {
         "console": {'level': 'DEBUG', "class": "logging.StreamHandler", "formatter": "verbose"},
    },
    "root": {
        "handlers": ["console"],
        "level": "DEBUG",
    },
}
```

2. And add following 3 lines of code to the place you want to log, like here in view:

```py
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from logging import getLogger # This 


logger = getLogger(__name__) # This

# Create your views here.
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "index.html"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        logger.info("Index page requested") # And this
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

This will render the following:

```
[2022-01-14 07:09:39,874] INFO: logged.views.Index page requested
14/Jan/2022:07:09:39 +0000 "GET / HTTP/1.1" status=200 res-time=18ms
```

Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/logging

Check the source code: https://github.com/almazkun/uwsgi_logging

Comment: Hi, I have tried the two steps you mentioned. Still cannot see the logs like you mentioned both by `supervisorctl tail -f myapplication` or `cat uwsgi.log`

Comment: That is interesting. What is the out put of the `tail /var/log/supervisor/*`? My example app writes logs to the `/var/log/supervisor/uwsgi.log`.

Comment: Finally, I can add the logs to the log file by both adding `--logto` and `--daemonize` https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Logging.html.